# Java 8 concurrent queue of semaphores

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

I need to make a queue with n semaphores so processes that did not enter due to size, stand in the waiting pool until the queue is free. When process have semaphore, ThreadPool runs its function in another thread. I also need a concurrent list of semaphore-carrying processes' IDs so that it is updated along with the semaphore queue. How can I do this using modern Java 8 patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strikes me that there is a much simpler solution that doesn't involve explicit semaphores and custom code (and bugs).

Just use a bounded `BlockingQueue` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)) and have the threads use `put(...)` to add items to the queue.  When queue is full, `put` will block the thread that is calling it ... until queue space is available.  If you don't want the thread to block indefinitely, use `offer` with a suitable timeout.